# In Firefox, how can I stop a jQuery slider and inspect its contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, slider, inspector

On this site there is a Slider: https://jetelements.zemez.io/slider/
I want to stop on the second slide and inspect its contents. But the slider slides away after a couple of seconds. How can I stop the slider right at the second slide and inspect it without it sliding away?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most sliders simply adjust inline styles to update the currently displayed slide. Some browser debuggers allow you to add DOM breakpoints. What you need is the "break on attribute modification". This pauses scripts that cause the element's attributes to change. In this case, inline styles. While paused, can then hop back to the DOM tab of your debugger to inspect the DOM.

Browser support can vary. I know [Chrome supports it](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#dom). Firefox [used to have it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Break_on_a_DOM_event).